# Creating 2 instances of the same printer in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, printing

I have a Cannon printer connected to my network. Windows 8 found it and I'm printing wirelessly successfully. But I often switch between printing 1 page for paper sheet, and 2 pages per paper sheet. Instead of updating the preferences for my printer each time I need to print, I'd like to create a 2<sup>nd</sup> instance of my printer.

One instance I would name Cannon_1page the other Cannon_2page.

Then I would print to the appropriate printer (instance) depending on my different preferences.

Is this possible to set up?

Comment: @OP: For spaces indenting triggers a sort of 'code-mode' over here.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, easily.

Go to your Printers folder (depending which way you go, you pick), and choose the option to add a new printer. When it asks what port, choose the existing port, and existing driver. Name it something different though.

Once it's created, you can right-click on the printer queue, choose **Printer Preferences...** and change your settings there. I do that exact thing with the Office MFPs in my building. One queue is Black and White, the other is Colour (and requires a password).

Comment: That's a fantastic idea!

Comment: Does this work for network printers also? Or only for USB attached printers. Thank you for this idea

Comment: Absolutely! Create the printer as I describe here: http://superuser.com/questions/556381/how-can-i-share-a-printer-on-windows-7-x64-with-windows-xp-x86/557943#557943

Comment: I don't understand the link leads to an article regarding Windows 7 and the post pointed to 557943 is not describing how to deal with a network printer. Thank you

Comment: Tried what is recommended. I went to printers, proceeded to add a printer, chose the same printer on my network and tried to rename it somthing different. Printer never appears in my list.

Comment: In my linked answer, you need to create a local port, named the share path for the printer